# heroku scheduled worker with node app - State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

I have a small node app which I'm running on a daily scheduled worker with Heroku (note this is my first experience using this feature with Heroku).

My app launches and runs fine, but as soon as I exit, it crashes.

```
2016-03-02T21:07:19.691014+00:00 app[web.1]: GOOD FINISH
2016-03-02T21:07:20.442770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-03-02T21:07:20.460125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Any ideas what's causing this? I've included the the basic starting and exiting code below -

```
var feed = require('../feed');

function good() {
  console.log('GOOD FINISH');
  exit();
}

function bad() {
 console.log('BAD FINISH')
 exit();
}

feed.run().then(good, bad);
```

Comment: Why do you call the exit() method?

Comment: I tried finding the source, but no luck, but anyways, I read somewhere that if you don't  run exit (and actually I now made the change to process.exit() ) and a connection remains open, node.js won't exit itself and your dyno could remain running